# mssql: Фильтрация по категориям каталога

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть проблема с фильтрацией - не работает. Посоветуйте пожалуйста что можно сделать.
Должно отобразиться согласно #CatalogueFilter только то где:

```
Категория 1 = 500, Категория 2 = 10009, Категория 3 - все что есть в рамках вышестоящих, Категория 4 - все что есть в рамках вышестоящих
и
Категория 1 = 500, Категория 2 = 12837, Категория 3 - 889, Категория 4 - все что есть в рамках вышестоящих
```

Условия WHERE кривые ((

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Catalogue
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #CatalogueFilter


CREATE TABLE #Catalogue
(
     id INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
    ,name VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL
    ,grp1 INTEGER NULL
    ,grp2 INTEGER NULL
    ,grp3  INTEGER NULL
    ,grp4  INTEGER NULL
)

CREATE TABLE #CatalogueFilter
(
     grp1 INTEGER NULL
    ,grp2 INTEGER NULL
    ,grp3  INTEGER NULL
    ,grp4  INTEGER NULL
)

INSERT INTO #Catalogue
(name,grp1, grp2, grp3, grp4)
VALUES
 ('Товар №1', 900, 5408, 12901, 5410)
,('Товар №2', 500, 10009, 8305, 8305)
,('Товар №3', 500, 10009, 8305, 8305)
,('Товар №4', 500, 10009, 8305, 8305)
,('Товар №5', 500, 10009, 8305, 8305)
,('Товар №6', 500, 884, 12855, 12855)
,('Товар №7', 500, 884, 12855, 12855)
,('Товар №8', 500, 12837, 889, 12846)
,('Товар №9', 500, 12837, 889, 12846)
,('Товар №10', 900, 870, 873, 14053)
,('Товар №11', 900, 1058, 12893, 12893)
,('Товар №12', 500, 10009, 8305, 8305)
,('Товар №13', 500, 10009, 8305, 8305)
,('Товар №14', 851, 7655, 7674, 7670)
,('Товар №15', 900, 5408, 12901, 5410)
,('Товар №16', 900, 5400, 14906, 7648)
,('Товар №17', 900, 1052, 1057, 14134)
,('Товар №18', 900, 5408, 12901, 5410)
,('Товар №19', 500, 10009, 8305, 8305)
,('Товар №20', 500, 10009, 8305, 8305)
,('Товар №21', 500, 10009, 8305, 8305)
,('Товар №22', 500, 10009, 8305, 8305)
,('Товар №23', 500, 10009, 8305, 8305)
,('Товар №24', 500, 10009, 8305, 8305)
,('Товар №25', 900, 1058, 12893, 12893)
,('Товар №26', 500, 12837, 889, 887)
,('Товар №27', 500, 12837, 889, 887)
,('Товар №28', 900, 12899, 901, 901)
,('Товар №29', 500, 10009, 8305, 8305)
,('Товар №30', 500, 10009, 8305, 8305)
,('Товар №31', 900, 12899, 901, 901)
,('Товар №32', 900, 5408, 12901, 5410)
,('Товар №33', 500, 10009, 8305, 8305)
,('Товар №34', 500, 10009, 8305, 8305)
,('Товар №35', 500, 10009, 8305, 8305)
,('Товар №36', 500, 10009, 8305, 8305)
,('Товар №37', 900, 1058, 1059, 1059)
,('Товар №38', 900, 5400, 14906, 7648)
,('Товар №39', 900, 12899, 901, 901)
,('Товар №40', 500, 10009, 8305, 8305)
,('Товар №41', 500, 10009, 8305, 8305)
,('Товар №42', 900, 5400, 14906, 7648)
,('Товар №43', 900, 12899, 901, 901)
,('Товар №44', 900, 5400, 14906, 7648)
,('Товар №45', 500, 10009, 886, 886)
,('Товар №46', 500, 10009, 886, 886)
,('Товар №47', 900, 1052, 1057, 14134)
,('Товар №48', 500, 884, 12855, 12855)
,('Товар №49', 500, 884, 12855, 12855)
,('Товар №50', 900, 1052, 1057, 14134);

INSERT INTO #CatalogueFilter
(grp1, grp2, grp3, grp4)
VALUES
    (500, 10009, NULL,NULL),
    (500, 12837, 889, NULL)

SELECT * FROM #CatalogueFilter;

SELECT 
    cat.*
    ,flt.*
FROM #Catalogue AS cat
LEFT JOIN #CatalogueFilter AS flt
ON cat.grp1 = flt.grp1
WHERE 1 = 1
    AND ((flt.grp4 IS NOT NULL AND cat.grp4 = flt.grp4) OR flt.grp4 IS NULL)
    AND ((flt.grp3 IS NOT NULL AND cat.grp3 = flt.grp3) OR flt.grp3 IS NULL)
    AND ((flt.grp2 IS NOT NULL AND cat.grp2 = flt.grp2) OR flt.grp2 IS NULL)
    AND ((flt.grp1 IS NOT NULL AND cat.grp1 = flt.grp1) OR flt.grp1 IS NULL)
```

Comment: А где собственно "эталонный" ответ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM #Catalogue t1
JOIN #CatalogueFilter t2 ON t1.grp1 = COALESCE(t2.grp1, t1.grp1)
                        AND t1.grp2 = COALESCE(t2.grp2, t1.grp2)
                        AND t1.grp3 = COALESCE(t2.grp3, t1.grp3)
                        AND t1.grp4 = COALESCE(t2.grp4, t1.grp4);
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a3762b29f0c40a4de08ea239619bfb76